# Несколько Pjax блоков на странице. Работает только первый. Второй перезагружает страницу

Tags: ajax, yii2, yii, pjax

День добрый!
Проблема с pjax. Он вообще рассчитан на 2 блока на странице? Блоки имеют разные ID. Второй блок работает неверно: страница перезагружается!

Pjax блок сделан в виде Yii2 виджета. Виджет просто вызывается дважды на странице!
Код основной функции виджета:

```
 public function run()
{
    $id_performer = $this->id_performer;
    $id_city = $this->id_city;
    $QueryItems = City::getItemsByPerformer($id_performer, $id_city);

    $countQuery = clone $QueryItems;
    $allCount = $countQuery->count();

    $haveMoreButton = \Yii::$app->params['perPage'] < $allCount;

    $items = $QueryItems->limit(\Yii::$app->params['perPage'])->all();
    return $this->render('items_widget', compact('items', 'haveMoreButton', 
    'id_performer', 'id_city'));
}
```

И код основного файла вида:

```
<?php $pjax = Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false, 'timeout' => false]);
$pjaxId = $pjax->getId();
$pjax->linkSelector = '#link' . $pjaxId;
?>
  <?php if (!empty($items)) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
       <?php include __DIR__ . '/../catalog-item.php'; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php if (isset($haveMoreButton) && $haveMoreButton): ?>
    <div>
    <?= Html::a('Show More', ['/site/pjax-news', 'limit' => (isset($limit) ? $limit 
    : (\Yii::$app->params['perPage'] * 2)), 'id_performer' => (isset($id_performer) 
    ? $id_performer : 0),'id_city' => (isset($id_city) ? $id_city : 0)],
    ['class' => 'btn big dark button_show_more', 'id' => 'link' . $pjaxId, 'data- 
    pjax' => 1]); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Очень жду ваших идей!